How can I seemlessly play multiple videos in loop with react?
I use the following code to play multiple videos in series
import React, { useState ,useEffect,useRef} from 'react'

export function VideoPlayer({playlist}) {

    const [currentlyPlaying, setCurrentlyPlaying] = useState(playlist[0]);


    const player=useRef(null);
    const playNext=()=>{
        let currentIndex=playlist.indexOf(currentlyPlaying);
        if(currentIndex<playlist.length-1){
            setCurrentlyPlaying(playlist[currentIndex+1]);
        }
        else{
            setCurrentlyPlaying(playlist[0]);
        }
        //reset the player
        player.current.load();

    }


    return (
        <div>
            <video width="320" height="240" controls ref={player} autoPlay onEnded={playNext} ref={player}>

                <source src={currentlyPlaying} type="video/mp4"/>
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
        </div>
    )


}

It works decent on desktop but on mobile it refreshes the controls each time, making it look awkawrd (the videos are only a few seconds long)
Is there a more seamless way to play video in series?

wouldnt removing the controls property have the wanted effect here? or do you require the user to be able to pause or play the video?

or you could even make a fancy property that marks if the viewport is mobile or desktop and change the controls properties based on this

feels like a bit of a stopgap solution.
All i want is a few videos playing in series as if they were one single video
